# Dictionary match issue with single pass multiple replacement

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, regular-language

Hi I'm trying to replace multiple words in a single pass using the function:

```
def multiple_replace(text, dict):
    regex = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(map(re.escape, dict.keys())))
    return regex.sub(lambda mo: dict[mo.string[mo.start():mo.end()]], text)
```

But my problem is that if I have a dictionary as:

```
dict = { 'hello1': 'hi', 'hello111' : 'GoodMorning', 'world' : 'earth' }
```

and I try

```
s = " hello111 world"
multiple_replace(s, dict)
```

The function matches `hello1` and not `hello111` as expected 
If you guys have any leads that would be great!

I thought to reverse the searching to be sure that the function starts with the longest keys as my keys are sorted but it's maybe not the best way.

Comment: Use word boundary - `regex = re.compile(r"\b(%s)\b" % "|".join(map(re.escape, dict.keys())))`. Or sort the keys by length in a descending order and use your non-word boundary approach.

Comment: Try using `regex = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(sorted(dict, key=lambda k: len(k), reverse=True)))` - does it work like that?

Answer (score -1):

**Wiktor Stribiżew**'s comment right

Sort the key first **OR** give the word boundary.

```
def multiple_replace_sort(text, a_dict):
    regex = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(map(re.escape, sorted(a_dict, key=lambda obj: len(obj), reverse=True))))
    return regex.sub(lambda mo: a_dict[mo.string[mo.start():mo.end()]], text)


def multiple_replace_boundary(text, a_dict):
    regex = re.compile(r"(%s)\b" % "|".join(map(re.escape, a_dict.keys())))
    return regex.sub(lambda mo: a_dict[mo.string[mo.start():mo.end()]], text)
```

> Non-word item may not suitable in above method, have to separate first, or maybe some better codes to handle it.

```
def multiple_replace_separate(text, a_dict):
    word, non_word = list(), list()
    for key in a_dict:
        word.append(key) if len(re.match(r'([a-zA-Z0-9]*)', key).group(0)) == len(key) else non_word.append(key)
    regex = re.compile(r"(%s)\B|(%s)\b" % ("|".join(non_word), "|".join(map(re.escape, word))))
    return regex.sub(lambda mo: a_dict[mo.string[mo.start():mo.end()]], text)
```

Comment: You do not need to use `.start()` and `.end()` of the match object to get the match value. Just get the value with `.group()`. Besides, your regex only uses a trailing word boundary, this it won't work. Word boundary approach won't work if the keys start/end with a non-word char.

Comment: Well, I just follow what the original code, and make the least changes. Using single word boundary `\b` at the group tail is for converting the most likely words.  And it works.

Comment: Then add a `world-` key and try again.

Comment: I see, then have to separate word and non-word first and ordering issue appear again. better just sort the keys =]